# Ruby tool to reformat array literals

Tags: ruby, sublimetext, rubymine, atom-editor, rubocop

Is there a Ruby tool or editor plugin that will convert an array literal into a %w array literal?

```
ARRAY = [
  "Foo",
  "Bar",
  "Baz"
]

ARRAY = %w(
  Foo
  Bar
  Baz
)
```

I know I could write my own regex to do this, but I'm hoping for something off-the-shelf. I'm already using Rubocop as a linter, but it doesn't cover it. I can't seem to find a plugin for RubyMine, Sublime, or Atom for it either.

Comment: I've never seen such a thing; Arrays can be defined in a lot of different ways. It'd be relatively easy to write something as a Vim macro, especially by recording it, but you're not using Vim.

Comment: Are you sure rubocop can't help? It looks like the word array cop p11y has mentioned is [enabled by default](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/config/enabled.yml#L698-L701)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rubocop -a` to autocorrect offenses. One of the default cops is [the word array cop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/style/word_array.rb), which should have you covered.

Comment: Ah, I see. That wasn't working for me because some of the elements have spaces in them. It is possible to have spaces in %W(style\ arrays) by escaping them with a backslash, but I can understand why that's not appropriate in every case.

Comment: If you have spaces better use normal syntax, it's confusing (or at least not intuitive) for human reading